# Normalization of Phase Noise / RF Power Spectrum to 1 Hz RBW

Tags: optics, power, fiber-optics, noise, photonics

I used a Rohde & Schwarz Phase Noise Analyzer to take some phase noise and RF spectrum measurements.

All in all, I'm trying to compute the linewidth of a laser from a measurement. I cannot detail my experimental setup here.

I know that the RBW determines the FFT bin size for your measurements. A lower RBW gives you enhanced precision in your measurement at the expense of increasing measurement time, if your RBW is too high you won't be able to resolve certain signals, so on and so forth.

I just want to know correction factor is to normalize a power measurement (in dBm/Hz) with a given RBW to a 1 Hz RBW. is it just:

$\text{Power}[\frac{\text{dBm/Hz}}{\text{Hz}}] = \text{Power[}\frac{\text{dBm/RBW[Hz]}}{\text{Hz}}] - 10\log_{10}(\text{RBW[Hz]})$

?

I haven't found a reference on this that does more than gloss over the computation, which is quite frustrating. It seems like a really basic thing, but I always end up with more questions than answers. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spectrum analyzer would typically report power integrated over some RBW bandwidth (reported power at frequency f is value integrated from f to f+RBW, assuming a square filter). If you want the power normalized to 1Hz (i.e. power spectral density in units dBm/Hz), use PSD [dBm/Hz] = power [dBm] - 10 log(RBW [Hz]).

This simple to derive. PSD [dBm/Hz] measures power from f to f+1Hz, while spectrum analyzer reports power from f to f+RBW. Assuming power is constant over the RBW bandwidth, PSD = power/RBW. Converting it to dBm: PSD [dBm/Hz] = 10 log(power/RBW) = 10 log(power) - 10 log(RBW) = power [dBm] - 10 log(RBW).